# MongoDB Atlas Connection - Traffic going to Primary Data Center

Tags: mongodb, go, mongodb-atlas

I'm connection to MongoDB using the below function written in Go

```
func Connect() (client *mongo.Client) {
    s = "mongodb+srv://" + os.Getenv("MONGO_ATLAS_USER_NAME") + ":" + os.Getenv("MONGO_ATLAS_PASSWORD") + "@" + os.Getenv("MONGO_ATLAS_HOST")
    cwt, _ := strconv.Atoi(os.Getenv("CONTEXT_WAIT_TIME"))
    ctx, cn := context.WithTimeout(context.Background(), time.Duration(rand.Intn(cwt))*time.Second)
    defer cn()
    options := options.Client().ApplyURI(s).SetReadPreference(readpref.Secondary()).SetReadConcern(readconcern.Local())
    options.SetMaxPoolSize(5000)
    client, e := mongo.Connect(ctx, options)
    CheckError(e)
    e = client.Ping(ctx, readpref.Secondary())
    CheckError(e)
    return
}
```

It should send all the requests to `Secondary` data centers but all the `Read IOPS` are visible on `Primary` instance.

I want to send all my read queries to the replicas.

I have checked this documentation already and have set the `Read Preference` as recommended
https://docs.atlas.mongodb.com/reference/replica-set-tags/index.html

This is the result on my dashboard. All the read queries are going to Primary instance and causing the `Disks IOPS` spikes
[image]

What I'm missing?

Comment: What driver documentation are you following that describes everything you are trying to do?